# Modify Gem, then ensure it gets reloaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've got a gem that I'm modified a bit of code in, but when I bundle install or update, the changes to the gem aren't reflected in my app.  Is there a way to ensure the changes are captured and reloaded in my app?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** update code directly in the gem. Instead, choose from one of these options (from preferred to less preferred):

- Send a pull request to the gem maintainer
- Monkey patch the gem in your app
- Fork the original gem and maintain your copy.

If you need help with any of this, that's a topic for another discussion, but please, don't edit code in the gem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you modify the installed gem by using bundle open .  Make the changes, save, then if your app is local and running in standard development mode (no caching) the changes will be immediate and worse case you can restart your app and they will be picked up.  If not, you aren't making the change to the gem your app is using.  A change like this will survive a bundle install, because bundler will have no reason to update your gem.  However, if you run bundle update and a new version of the modified gem is installed it will get rid of your change.  A good approach is to fork the original gem on github, make your change and have your app point to your forked copy on github.. then even when you deploy the app it will find and install your modified code.  Also if the change is something useful for everyone, make a pull request to the original project.